# PostgreSQL query - return all results with field with past 5 minutes

Tags: postgresql

Hey everyone. Here is my situation... I need to craft a sql query against a postgresql server that will return all records created within the past 5 minutes, *rounded down to the lowest minute*. So if cron kicks the query off at 12:05:25.000, it needs to query all records created since 12:00:00.000. So I guess I really have two issues.

- I know using

  DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL
     5 MINUTE)

  works in mysql - is there
  an equivalent in postgresql? I
  couldn't find any mention of it in
  the date/time functions documentation
  [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html).
- Second, how do I tell it to round
  down to the minute (ignore seconds)
  for the 5 minute interval?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

```
select current_timestamp - interval '5' minute
```

And to eliminate the seconds

```
select current_timestamp - interval '5' minute - 
  (extract(seconds from current_timestamp) || 'seconds')::interval
```

Comment: or `date_trunc('minute', t)` to eliminate the seconds.